# Codeigniter, when I try to update, the single quote displays as &#039;

Tags: codeigniter-3

I like set_value. Every time, when I try to update the post, the single quote displays as &#039 ;. Not only single quote, some characters display too. Please, help me

Im using Codeigniter 3, Php 7

**View**

```
$description = array(
        'name' => 'description',
        'type' => 'text',
        'placeholder' => 'description',
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'rows' => '3',
        'value' => set_value('description', $post->INTRO_DESCRIPTION),
    );


<div class="form-group">
  <label for="description" class="col-md-2 control-label">Details</label>
  <div class="col-md-10"><?php echo form_textarea($description); ?></div>
  <div class="col-md-10"><?php echo form_error('description', '<div class="text-danger">', '</div>'); ?></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the solution. And it's very simple. Just adding "false" at end of the set_value.

```
set_value('description', $post->INTRO_DESCRIPTION, FALSE)
```